# PHP script generates an unwanted strange additional column

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, html-table

I'm trying to solve this issue for about 5 hours now and I don't do any progress. :( I've got a PHP script which does a SQL query. In a while loop it should output table rows with a defined number of columns. I've reduced the script to a minimum without any variables. There are 6 defined columns within the while loop, but the script creates another (empty) one after the column *vol*, so I have 7 at the end.

I have no idea, what the problem could be. Did anyone of you anytime experience something similar? The code:

```
$sql_events = "SELECT * FROM events ORDER BY eventID ASC";
$allevents = mysqli_query($db, $sql_events);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($allevents)){
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>ID</td>";
  echo "<td>date</td>";
  echo "<td>vol<td/>";
  echo "<td>5</td>";
  echo "<td>value</td>";
  echo "<td>actions</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

And the HTML result of this:

```
<tr>
  <td>ID</td>
  <td>date</td>
  <td>vol</td>
  <td></td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>value</td>
  <td>actions</td>
</tr>
```

I do use the same script for another table in the same database and it is working properly. I have no idea what I could additionally check and every hint is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a markup error in this line:

```
  echo "<td>vol<td/>";
```

Change it to:

```
  echo "<td>vol</td>";
```

The extra markup you see is generated by your browser to prevent the HTML error.

Answer (score 0):

```
<td>vol<td/> change to <td>vol</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sql_events = "SELECT * FROM events ORDER BY eventID ASC";
$allevents = mysqli_query($db, $sql_events);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($allevents)){
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>ID</td>";
  echo "<td>date</td>";
  echo "<td>vol<td/>";
  echo "<td>5</td>";
  echo "<td>value</td>";
  echo "<td>actions</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

your vol has the forward slash in the wrong location.

```
<td>vol</td>
```

Comment: that's a forward slash. backslash is ``\``.